# Delphi Baas Parse Query Limits 100 record

Tags: delphi, parse-platform

I'm testing Parse Baas service for Delphi XE8.

The program return only 100 records (default limitation from Parse).

How to change this limitation and download all records to client delphi side?

```
procedure TForm1.RefreshList;
var
  LJSONArray : TJSONArray;
  LItem: TListViewItem;
  I: Integer;
begin
  LJSONArray := TJSONArray.Create;
  try

    BackendStorage1.Storage.QueryObjects('Lists', [], LJSONArray);
    ListView1.ClearItems;
    for I := 0 to LJSONArray.Count-1 do
    begin
      LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
      LItem.Text := (LJSonArray.Items[I].GetValue<string>('Name'));
    end;
  finally
    LJSONArray.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the limit as a parameter:

```
QueryObjects('Lists', ['limit=1000'], LJSONArray);
```

You cannot get more than 1000 records in one go from Parse. To retreive the next 1000 records use the skip parameter:

```
QueryObjects('Lists', ['limit=1000', 'skip=1000'], LJSONArray);
```

Although that might work, you should consider to restrict the number of objects returned with a meaningful condition.

Comment: I made {BackendStorage1.Storage.QueryObjects('Lists', ['Limit=1000'], LJSONArray);}, no changes (100 recs)

Comment: Can you try again with "Limit" changed to lowercase? As a Delphi developer I often forget  that those things tend to be case sensitive. If that works I will adjust my answer accordingly.